# C: Error expected expression before "struct name2

Tags: c

Here's the declaration of the struct in "sprite.h"

```
typedef struct {
  int x,y;             /**< current sprite position */
  int width, height;   /**< sprite dimensions */
  int xspeed, yspeed;  /**< current speeds in the x and y direction */
  char *map;           /**< the sprite pixmap (use read_xpm()) */
} Sprite;
```

And here's the pieces of code where we make use of them, in separate source files where we include the header.

```
Sprite *create_sprite(char *pic[], int x, int y, int xspeed, int yspeed) {
    //allocate space for the "object"
    Sprite *sp = (Sprite *) malloc ( sizeof(Sprite));
    if( sp == NULL )
        return NULL;
    // read the sprite pixmap
    sp->map = read_xpm(pic, &(sp->width), &(sp->height));
    if( sp->map == NULL ) {
        free(sp);
        return NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        sp->x =x;
        sp->y =y;
        sp->xspeed = xspeed;
        sp->yspeed = yspeed;
    }

    return sp;
}
```

and

```
if(xi==xf)
    Sprite* sp = create_sprite(xpm, xi, yi,0,speed); //error
else
    Sprite* sp = create_sprite(xpm, xi, yi,speed,0); //error
```

This last piece of code is used in one of our "main" functions. When we try to compile our project using `make` we get the error in the title, refering to the expressions signaled above. Eclipse also doesn't highlight `Sprite` outside of the header file...

Comment: Check for a typedef or #define that includes `struct name2`.  There's probably a substitution going on you're not aware of.

Comment: You can't usefully create the sprite pointer variable in the bodies of the `if` and `else` because the variable goes out of scope immediately.  Use `Sprite *sp;` before the `if` and then `sp = create_sprite(...);` in the bodies of the `if` and `else`.  Consider creating an `xspeed` and `yspeed` variable in the calling code, and setting one to 0 and one to `speed`, and then using a single call to `create_sprite(xpm, xi, yi, xspeed, yspeed);`.

Comment: If you want to confuse the readers, write `Sprite* sp = create_sprite(xpm, xi, yi, (xi!=xf)*speed, (xi==xf)*speed);`

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, you can't usefully create the `Sprite` pointer variable in the bodies of the `if` and `else` because the variable goes out of scope immediately.  It's equivalent to writing this — except this would compile but any reference to `sp` after the `if`/`else` would fail (undefined variable):

```
if (xi == xf)
{
    Sprite* sp = create_sprite(xpm, xi, yi, 0, speed);
}
else
{
    Sprite* sp = create_sprite(xpm, xi, yi, speed, 0);
}
```

The simplest fix is to define `Sprite *sp;` before the `if` and then have simple assignments (`sp = create_sprite(...);`) in the bodies of the `if` and `else`.

```
Sprite *sp;
if (xi == xf)
    sp = create_sprite(xpm, xi, yi, 0, speed);
else
    sp = create_sprite(xpm, xi, yi, speed, 0);
```

Consider creating variables `xspeed` and `yspeed` in the calling code, and setting one to 0 and one to `speed`, and then using a single call to `create_sprite(xpm, xi, yi, xspeed, yspeed);`, like this:

```
int xspeed = 0;
int yspeed = 0;

if (xi == xf)
    yspeed = speed;
else
    xspeed = speed;

Sprite *sp = create_sprite(xpm, xi, yi, xspeed, yspeed);
```